# Отменить ховер на элементе при клике на нем

Tags: javascript, css, css3, события

Попытался свою ситуацию воспроизвести в [codepen-е](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/VPzYbb). Ниже - запускаемый код.
Принцип такой:

1. Ховерете красный квадратик, он расширяется.
2. Как расширился, кликаете по центру, после клика **не отводить
   курсор**.
3. После клика появился другой квадратик на месте красного, его прежних размеров.
   Если попытаться повертеть мышкой по этому квадратику, то ховер с
   красного пропадет, и он уменьшится в размерах.

Так вот, как после клика завершить ховер на красном квадрате, чтобы его транзишн вернулся в исходное положение? Если не вертеть мышкой, красный квадратик так и будет показываться после клика.  
**Разметку менять никак нельзя**, рассчитываю на решение через js на 90%, остальное - css, но тут уже вряд ли он сможет помочь...

```js
$(".one, .two").click(function(){
  $(".two").toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
html body span {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
html body .one {
  background-color: red;
}
html body .one:hover {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
html body .two {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
html body .two.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="two"></span>
```

Comment: самое простое - добавить по клику класс настройки которого будут перебивать настройки hover

Comment: Grudy, и так там уже класс на классе классом погоняет, не хотелось бы всё на классах завязывать... Я предположил, что есть какой-нибудь обработчик на js для этого. Разве нет?

Comment: Grudy, кое-что накопал тем временем: https://habrahabr.ru/post/113073/

Comment: @VostokSisters, прошу вас, отныне, сразу уточнять все нюансы, что бы не подставлять других пользователей

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавляете дополнительный класс и в CSS уточняете, что увеличивать только тогда, когда у элемента нет этого класса:

```js
$(".one, .two").click(function(){
  $(".two").toggleClass('show');
  $(".one").toggleClass('no-hover');
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
html body span {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
html body .one {
  background-color: red;
}
html body .one:hover:not(.no-hover) {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
html body .two {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
html body .two.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="two"></span>
```

Comment: Прекрасно работает. Думаю, пойдет. Правда не понимаю как работает :D Объясните для ребёнка эту строчку, пожалуйста: `.one:hover:not(.no-hover)`, как она выполняется?

Comment: @VostokSisters, она означает, что нужно выполнять `hover` только если у элемента нету класса `.no-hover`

Comment: У меня в деле заместо конкретного класса `.one` будет конкретный тег `article`. Если написать `.article:hover:not(.no-hover)`, то стиль будет применяться ко всем тегам `article`? Правильно понимаю работу селектора? Или это всё равно что думать, что раз написано `article:hover`, то ховер применяется ко всем элементом при ховере?)

Comment: @VostokSisters, `hover` будет применяться ко всем `.article`, только если у них нет класса `.no-hover`

Comment: А что если я хочу запретить всем `article` ховер, когда я уже кликнул по одному из них? Только тугглить класс всем 500 артиклам не нужно) Как тогда написать селектор?

Comment: Просто бывает, что если оставить страниц на минут 15 без использования, то вставка в src в img в оверлее происходит какое-то время (иногда секунды 2 - максимум), таким образом, если начать водить по другим артиклям, то ховер будет всё равно происходить (за исключением того, что уже был выбран для показа). Поэтому хотелось бы всем исклюить сразу...

Comment: @VostokSisters, я не понял вопроса

Comment: Запретить всем элементам article ховер, когда я уже по одному из них кликнул. Как это сделать? Только без туггления класса всем элементам. Как такое сделать?

Comment: @VostokSisters, можно применять класс родительскому элементу и hover делать через него. Когда нажал на один блок, то прибавалется класс родителю и ховер уже не работает

Comment: Да, неплохой совет, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

При клике переключать класс `active` первому спану; добавить классу `active` такие же свойства, как и при ховере.

```js
$(".one, .two").click(function(){
  $(".two").toggleClass('show');
  $(".one").toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
html body span {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
html body .one {
  background-color: red;
}
html body .one:hover,
html body .one.active {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
html body .two {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
html body .two.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="two"></span>
```

Comment: А почему не посоветовал просто засунуть спан в спан? То же самое бы получилось, что и у тебя. Но с моим вопросом это вообще ничего общего не имеет. Я вообще по пунктам всё расписан, но всё равно меня не поняли. Нет, менять разметку нельзя. В оригинальной проблеме спан1 - картинка, спан2 - оверлей на весь экран, что там поменять местами-то? Вспомнил как раз, что забыл js указать в теги.

Comment: Вот оригинальная [проблема](https://vostoksisters.github.io/gallery/somethingserious/). Если нажать на картинку, вылезет оверлей, и если при этом НЕ убирать курсор от начал до конца, то ховер на картинке продолжет существовать. Это огорчает мои чувства перфекциониста.

Comment: Если есть какие-то строгие параметры, которые должны быть соблюдены, то стоит написать об этом явно )
Счас переделаю ответ.

Comment: Цитирую из вопроса: "Так вот, как после клика завершить ховер на красном квадрате, чтобы его транзишн вернулся в исходное положение? "

Comment: Я не придираюсь конкретно уж, такой уж вопрос... По клику - показ сиреневого квадрата, одновременно с этим - возврат в начальное состояние красного, и всё это не отводя курсора.

Comment: Теперь понятно, но уже есть ответ. Пример с галереей меня еще больше запутал, я подумал, что необходимо сохранять состояние при наведении для блока с картинкой даже при открытом оверлее.

Comment: А всё как раз наоборот) Бывает.